# Why doesn't the color of the snackbar change?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change the background and color of the inscription for the snackbar component. But when I set the style has not changed.  How to do it right?

ts:

```
this._snackBar.open('Test', 'Done!', {
  verticalPosition: 'top',
  horizontalPosition: 'end',
  duration: 2500,
  panelClass: ['test']
 });
```

css:

```
.test {
    background: #1abc9c;
    color     : blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `::ng-deep`, or declare it in a global style file(default `src/styles.css`).

Because it is created in the body using the [CDK Overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview), the component style scope does not work for it.

```css
::ng-deep .test {
  background: #1abc9c;
  color     : blue;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrwxbw?file=app%2Fsnack-bar-component-example.css

Answer (score 0):

Hi you nedd to override mat-snack-bar-container class

```
.mat-snack-bar-container {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    background: #323232; // change the color here
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```